# Which tool for Android to find & manage duplicate files without cleaning aim?

Tags: duplicate-files, android-app

I am searching for a tool for Android which can universally help to manage duplicate files, triplicate files etc.

At end perhaps to select some for deletion - but at end, and perhaps.

All tools I found combine finding duplicates with cleaning, and emphasize deletion. Thus all are not usable.

The reason for my trouble is that once again on my SD card (plugged in the slot of Samsung Galaxy 10+, Android 12) very many files are lost or are rearranged.

Partly this may be due to my rearrage activities for bringing files into new created directories by not only copy but rather by command move.

Thus the simplest application of a find-duplicates tool I need is:

Files are directly under /storage/3530-3234.

Created new directory
/storage/3530-3234/WEsubdir.

Now not directly to move the files into the new directory, but to run search. In the list of search results to mark the files, and to copy the files without move. Then to use a find-duplicate tool to prove if copying was correct.  Then to delete according to the search-result list.

When a tool each time start to scan the whole storage device, as most known tools do, that is not the right way. I need to control what range_1 of storage device_a is to be compared with what range_2 of storage device_b regarding duplicates.

Neither in Android nor in Linux are usable tools available, as I found.

Please does someone know a tool, a solution.

Regards

Comment: [`jdupes`](https://www.jdupes.com/)

Comment: Many decent enough file manager apps will have that.

Comment: Only app "Duplicate Cleaner" by DigitalVolcano offers options that perhaps can do that, as my knowledge, but this app is for Microsoft Windows, Regards

Comment: There are many other windows apps that can do the same, and soem are free https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=Duplicate%20Cleaner

Comment: seems to be a misunderstanding: I intended to write thar I do  n o t   use Windows; I need for Android 12 a tool to find and manage duplicates in range_a on storage device_1 comparing with range_b on storing device_2, where storage devices include SD card and USB sticks. Finding is the aim, not deletion. I have tested about 30 to 40 Apps in Google Play Store, nearly all, no usable found. Regards.